# Anaconda 32bit, 64bitの両方をインストールすると、スタートメニューに64bitのAnaconda promptが表示されない

Tags: windows, anaconda

Anacondaを32bit, 64bitの両方をインストールしました。

32bitの方はスタートメニューにAnaconda promptが表示されますが、64bitの方が表示されません。

しかし、フォルダにそのショートカットファイルがあるのは確かです。

再インストールを何度も試みたり、ショートカットをマニュアルで作り直してもスタートメニューに表示されない現象が起こっております。対処方法をご教授いただけますでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: どちらを先にインストールしたかと、それぞれのインストール時のオプション選択や対象ディレクトリ指定をすべて追記してみてください。ちなみに先に32bitをインストールし、両方とも「Just Me」でディレクトリは32bitはユーザーのホームディレクトリの「anaconda3」で64bitは同じく「anaconda6」、両方ともPATHには追加せず、両方ともデフォルトPythonとして登録するとしてインストールした場合、ちゃんと両方ともスタートメニューに表示されました。

Comment: 一般的にはどちらか一方をインストールするだけで十分そうですが、本当に共存は必要ですか？

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。インストールは64bitのみでも行ってみましたが、32bitの有る無しにかかわらず、スタートメニューに表示されませんでした。インストール条件はJust Me, Path指定無しです。

Comment: 今回、起きた現象のバージョンはAnaconda3-5.2.0でした。バージョンを最新のAnaconda3-2021.11にした場合はPromptがスタートメニューに表示されました。バージョンの影響もあるかもしれません。

Comment: ちなみに32bitを使用する理由としては、使用するDLLが64bit では動かないためです。また、tensorflowは64bitでないとインストールできないため、共存が必要となりました。

Comment: 解決したようなので、その状況や対策を自己回答でもしておいてください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

無事に本件を解決できました。
アドバイスいただき、ありがとうございました。